# PHP scandir() on Windows Server Won't Look Past 'C:\Users'

Tags: php, windows

I'm running a Windows VM setup with IIS and PHP 5.3.28.

Basically I am scanning a directory:

```
$dir    = 'C:\Users';
$files = scandir($dir);
print_r($files);
```

Which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => .NET v4.5
    [3] => .NET v4.5 Classic
    [4] => All Users
    [5] => Default
    [6] => Default User
    [7] => New folder
    [8] => Public
    [9] => desktop.ini
    [10] => my-folder
)
```

Now if I try and go further:

```
$dir    = 'C:\Users\my-folder';
$files = scandir($dir);
```

I get nothing... I checked the permissions of 'my-folder' and they are 777.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Are the folder permissions on C:\Users\ recursive? Does PHP have access to the folder? I believe you may have missed a permission to tweak or two, this is common in Windows.